# How do I copy a template

Tags: templates, joomla-5.x

In Joomla 3 there was a handy button to create a copy of template so that you had a basis on which to customise and create your own template.

This seems to have been removed in J5 and instead there is a create child template button which is not at all what I want. I want an entirely separate template to customise which is not linked to a parent.

What is the best way do do this now? (and why on earth was the facility removed - it was really useful) ?

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to duplicate a template in Joomla 5. - Do the following:

- go to "System" on backend
- Click on "Site Template Styles"
- Check the box beside the Template you want to duplicate
- If you check the box the Duplicate button becomes available on the top

I hope this helps...

Comment: er, no. That is not what I want. All that does is make a duplicate of the template style settings in the template_styles table in the database.  So you can have more than one set of style settings for a given template (default colours etc) for different parts of your site.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a long comment @Gerald

er, no. That is not what I want. All that does is make a duplicate of the template style settings in the template_styles table in the database.  So you can have more than one set of style settings for a given template (default colours etc) for different parts of your site.

What I am after is the old J3 facility to create a copy of the actual template files and install it as a fresh template that you can then customise. It was quite handy for creating a copy of a template to modify that wouldn't get overwritten by updates.

The only way to do it now is manually by zipping up the template folder and the template's media folder  and copying them to new folders with a new name and manually editing all of the references to the old template name so that the namespacing etc all works and doesn't get confused. Not so simple as it was in J3 which is probably why they couldn't be arsed to include it in J5.